# How to set projection for concatenated result of two columns in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have a problem to get concatenated result of two columns into single result in Hibernate 
Criteria.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT firstName || ' ' || lastName FROM person WHERE active_yn='Y'
```

How to set projection for concatenated result of two columns in Hibernate Criteria?

Comment: what is that problem? can you give more details?

Comment: I want to write above SQL query in Hibernate Criteria

Answer (score 0):

```
/ an elegant alternative?
criteria.like(Expression.concat(firstname, ' ', lastName), input);
// an sql-like function?
criteria.like("concat(firstName, ' ', lastName)", input);
// perhaps a database-dependent concatenator?
criteria.like("firstName + ' ' + lastName");
criteria.like("firstName || ' ' || lastName");
```

[More ref](http://whaticode.com/2013/02/01/hibernate-criteria-concatenate-fields-in-like-and-ilike-operators/)